# How to add second res folder

Tags: android-studio, directory

Before the last update i could easily create a second res folder that holds another design for my app. This i did by just creating a new res-memory folder inside the project explorer. Than i had to include the sourceSets in the build.gradle file, like this.:

```
sourceSets{
    main{
        res{
            srcDir 'src/main/res-memory'
        }
    }
}
```

Than this new res would show up in the project explorer and could be used like the main res folder.

However, after the update i cannot get this to work. The folder is only visible if i go to the projects directory though windows file explorer. But not visible in the AS project explorer so i cannot easily add stuff to it. These are the exact steps that i do.

1. Right click app folder > new Res folder
2. Change folder location to src/main/res-memory, with target source set main
3. Add the above code snippet to the build.grade file

However, the folder is not visible in my project explorer. Before it should up under the original res folder. So the structure was

```
main
  >res
    >>Drawable etc..
  >res-memory
    >>drawable etc..
```

So how to correctly add a res folder that holds other design in android studio. This is the main reason i switched from eclipse, bc eclipse dont allow two res folder.

I have tried to clean and rebuild the project, as well as not changing the folder location by using the default res/2

Comment: Have you tried just to add productFlavours to your project and every res keep in different productFlavour? As example created 2 productFlavours in your build.gradle (design1, design2), then create 2 folders design1 and design2 next to main folder, and put there res folders for every design (and remove res from main)